# Clicar em uma imagem centralizada e arrasta-lá para o link da esquerda ou link da direita?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seria essa a imagem centralizada no meio da página...do lado direito um link e do esquerdo outro link ...o usuário teria que clicar nessa imagem e arrastar pra entrar nos links...

Comment: para fazer isso, existe a biblioteca: [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você pode monitorar a direção para onde o circulo foi movido usando os eventos `dragstart` e `dragend`, para tal pode analizar as propriedades como `x`, `clientX`, `screenX`.

desta forma no `dragend`, você pode tomar uma ação caso ele se mova para a esquerda ou direita.

no exemplo abaixo esperimente arrastar o circulo para a esquerda ou direita.

```js
var circulo = document.getElementById("circulo");
var screenX = 0;
var pos = "centro";

circulo.addEventListener("dragstart", function (event) {
  screenX = event.screenX;
});

circulo.addEventListener("dragend", function (event) {  
  var aux = event.screenX > screenX ? "direita" : "esquerda";
  if (pos != aux) {
    circulo.classList.remove(pos);  
    pos = pos == "centro" ? aux : "centro";
    circulo.classList.add(pos);
  }  
});

circulo.addEventListener("transitionend", function (event) {
  if (event.propertyName == "left") {
    console.log("circulo movido para a " + pos);
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#circulo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 1s;  
}

#circulo svg {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 0px 0px 5px black );
  filter: drop-shadow( 0px 0px 5px black );
}

#circulo path {
  fill: darkorange;
  transition: fill 1s; 
}

#circulo.esquerda {
  right: 100%;
  left: -100px;
}

#circulo.direita {
  left: calc(100% - 100px);
}

#circulo.esquerda path {
  fill: crimson;
}

#circulo.direita path {
  fill: teal;
}
```

```html
<div id="circulo" class="centro" draggable="true">
  <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 294.843 294.843" style="enable-background:new 0 0 294.843 294.843;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path d="M199.628,175.487c-0.632-1.977,0.067-4.131,1.741-5.358l37.422-27.455c5.958-4.371,8.333-11.736,6.049-18.763   c-2.283-7.028-8.533-11.591-15.922-11.625l-46.413-0.215c-2.076-0.01-3.908-1.34-4.558-3.311l-14.547-44.076   c-2.316-7.017-8.586-11.55-15.975-11.551h0c-7.389,0-13.66,4.534-15.976,11.55l-6.557,19.859c-1.039,3.146,0.669,6.54,3.816,7.578   c3.147,1.041,6.539-0.669,7.579-3.816l6.557-19.859c1.014-3.073,3.762-3.312,4.581-3.312c0.818,0,3.566,0.239,4.58,3.312   l14.547,44.077c2.27,6.875,8.658,11.516,15.897,11.55l46.413,0.215c3.236,0.015,4.313,2.555,4.565,3.333   c0.253,0.778,0.875,3.465-1.734,5.379l-37.423,27.455c-5.837,4.283-8.277,11.793-6.072,18.689l14.143,44.222   c0.986,3.083-1.097,4.892-1.759,5.372c-0.662,0.481-3.025,1.904-5.652,0.013l-37.677-27.114c-5.878-4.229-13.776-4.229-19.654,0   l-37.684,27.119c-2.627,1.89-4.991,0.468-5.652-0.012c-0.662-0.481-2.745-2.289-1.76-5.371l14.139-44.229   c2.205-6.895-0.236-14.405-6.072-18.688l-37.421-27.455c-2.609-1.914-1.987-4.602-1.734-5.379c0.253-0.778,1.33-3.318,4.565-3.333   l46.416-0.215c3.313-0.016,5.987-2.714,5.972-6.028c-0.016-3.304-2.699-5.972-6-5.972c-0.009,0-0.019,0-0.028,0l-46.416,0.215   c-7.389,0.034-13.639,4.597-15.922,11.625c-2.283,7.028,0.091,14.393,6.048,18.764l37.421,27.455   c1.673,1.228,2.373,3.381,1.741,5.358l-14.138,44.229c-2.25,7.038,0.159,14.392,6.137,18.734c3,2.179,6.442,3.269,9.886,3.269   c3.419,0,6.84-1.075,9.829-3.225l37.683-27.119c1.685-1.213,3.95-1.213,5.635,0l37.677,27.114c5.998,4.316,13.736,4.3,19.715-0.044   c5.979-4.343,8.387-11.697,6.136-18.736L199.628,175.487z"/>
    <path d="M147.421,0C66.133,0,0,66.133,0,147.421s66.133,147.421,147.421,147.421c3.313,0,6-2.687,6-6s-2.687-6-6-6   C72.75,282.843,12,222.093,12,147.421S72.75,12,147.421,12s135.421,60.75,135.421,135.421c0,46.48-23.42,89.182-62.65,114.228   c-2.793,1.783-3.612,5.493-1.829,8.286c1.783,2.793,5.492,3.612,8.286,1.829c42.7-27.262,68.193-73.745,68.193-124.342   C294.843,66.133,228.71,0,147.421,0z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigada...tem como eu fazer isso só que com o :hover?

Comment: @MichellySabatiny, como você pretende defenir a direção que pretende mover o circulo usando o `:hover`?

Comment: Então voei aqui...já consegui meu objetivo deu certo ...obrigada

Comment: @MichellySabatiny, fiz umas melhorias no script.

Comment: Obrigada por me ajudar @TobyMosque ...